# Does the Cost Function matter when CODING Logistic Regression

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

NOTE: when you see (0) in the functions it represents Theta not Zero

I've been studying Andrew Ng's Machine Learning Course, and I have the following inquery:

(Short Version: If one were to look at all the mathematical expressions/calculations used for both Forward AND Backward propagation, then it appears to me that we never use the Cost Function directly, but its **Derivative** , so what is the importance of the cost function and its choice anyway? is it purely to evaluate our system whenever we feel like it?)

Andrew mentioned that for Logistic Regression, using the MSE (Mean Squared Error) Cost function

[image: MSE (Mean Squared Error) Cost Function]

wouldn't be good, because applying it to our Sigmoid function would yield a non-convex cost function that has a lot of Local Optima, so it is best that we use the following logistic cost function:

[image]

Which will have 2 graphs (one for y=0 and one for y=1), both of which are convex.

My question is the following, since it is our objective to minimize the cost function (aka have the Derivative reach 0), which we achieve by using Gradient Descent, updating our weights using the **Derivative** of the Cost Function, which in both cases (both cost functions) is the same derivative:

dJ = (h0(x(i)) - y(i)) . x(i)

So how did the different choice of cost function in this case effect our algorithm in any way? because in forward propagation, all we need is
h0(x(i)) = Sigmoid(0Tx)
which can be calculated without ever needing to calculate the cost function, then in backward propagation and in updating the weights, we always use the derivative of the cost function, so when does the Cost Function itself come into play? is it just necessary when we want an indication of how well our network is doing? (then why not just depend on the derivative to know that)

Comment: Well, cost function matters because in backward pass the gradients are calculated using the cost function. That way the learning take place. Without a loss function you cannot apply gradient descent.

Comment: Backpropagation and its calculations are still a little fuzzy for me, but I've realized it's where my misconceptions lie, I'll make sure I understand it better, thanks for your comment

Comment: The foundations of backpropagation was explained first in [this](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a164453.pdf) paper. I have wrote a medium post [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/backpropagation-paper-from-scratch-796793789248) as a walk-through for the paper and essence of backpropagation. It includes useful notebook implementation as well, maybe it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll get right on it

Answer (score 1):

The forward propagation does not need the cost function in any way because you just applying all your learned weights to the corresponding input.

The cost function is generally used to measure how good your algorihm is by comparing your models outcome (therefore applying your current weights to your input) with the true label of the input (in supervised algorithms). The main objective is therefore to minimize the cost function error as (in most cases) you want the difference of the prediction and the true label as small as possible. In optimization it is pretty helpful if your function you want to optimize is convex because it guarantees that if you find a local minimum it is at the same time the global minimum.

For minimizing the cost function, gradient descent is used to iteratively update your weights to get closer to the minimum. This is done w.r.t to the learned weights such that you are able to update your weights of the model for achieving the lowest possible costs. The backpropagation algorithm is used to adjust the weights using the cost function in the backward pass.

Comment: I've realized my misconception is related to how backpropagation is calculated/done.. thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you are correct: we do not explicitly use the cost function in any of the calculations for forward propagation and back propagation.

You asked 'what is the importance of the cost function and its choice anyway?'. I have two answers:

1. The cost function is incredibly important because its gradient is what allows us to update our weights. Although we are only actually computing the gradient of the cost function and not the cost function itself, choosing a different cost function would mean we would have a different gradient, thus changing how we update our weights.
2. The cost function allows us to evaluate our model performance. It is common practice to plot cost vs epoch to understand how the cost decreases over time.

Your answer indicted you essentially understood all of this already but I hoped to clarify it a bit. Thanks!